# Google Apps Script copying data to wrong sheet

Tags: google-sheets-macros

I am using this code which is supposed to copy data from "REQUEST" sheet to "MASTER" sheet but actually the code copies data to "MASTER" sheet as well as some other sheet also in the file.

```
function onFormSubit () {
 var app = SpreadsheetApp;
 var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var shtForm = ss.getSheetByName("REQUEST");
 var shtAgrt = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");
 var rcrdCount = shtAgrt.getRange(1, 25).getValue();
 var chkNum = shtForm.getRange(Math.max(shtForm.getLastRow(),2),1).getValue();
  shtAgrt.getRange(rcrdCount+1, 2).setValue(chkNum);
}
```

I don't want the code to copy data to any other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what happened but error is gone away now. Perhaps it went away after deleting all form submit data or after refreshing google sheet.